# Node Error Must use import to load ES module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have the following code:

```
import { toString } from 'nlcst-to-string';
import { retext } from 'retext';
import retextPos from 'retext-pos';
import retextKeywords from 'retext-keywords';


const sentence =
"President Obama woke up Monday facing a Congressional defeat that many in both parties believed could hobble his presidency."


function process(params) {
    // some code

}

exports.main = processComment;
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES module
```

Which is strange because I already am using import.

I have also tried adding `"type": "module"` to `package.json` - no luck. Tried ending the file extension in `.mjs` - nothing

Answer (score 0):

It’s either your node version or None of your import locations have `./`

Even if those files are in the same directory as your main js file you still need that.

Unless that’s so npm library I have never heard of.

Comment: Can you explain the `./` point more? I just changed it to `import {toString} from './nlcst-to-string'` and it doesn't work. All the modules are in a `node_modules` folder that comes with NPM

Comment: Well if they are from an npm it’s not needed. But if you were importing from a script you wrote you would need `./folder/filename ` it’s just pathing the route to your file. `./' means the route directory of your project.

Comment: What version of node are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Check your node version. Node version 14+ supports the type: "module"

```
node --version
```

If you have node version manager, you can run

```
nvm install your_desired_version_here
```

to get a compliant version